# Convert rows to columns in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to convert the below data into  the output.  Eg: There are 8 unique areas in the below table and an id can have max of only 4 areas of amount.
Input table:

| ID | Area | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 101 |
| 1 | 2341 | 200 |
| 1 | 3214 | 100 |
| 2 | 1234 | 300 |
| 2 | 4321 | 100 |
| 2 | 2341 | 290 |
| 2 | 4351 | 222 |
| 3 | 3255 | 380 |
| 3 | 3214 | 190 |
| 3 | 5431 | 200 |
| 3 | 4444 | 100 |

Output table:

| ID | Area1 | Amount1 | Area2 | Amount2 | Area3 | Amount3 | Area4 | Amount4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1234 | 101 | 2341 | 200 | 3214 | 100 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | 1234 | 300 | 4321 | 100 | 2341 | 290 | 4351 | 222 |
| 3 | 3255 | 380 | 3214 | 190 | 5431 | 200 | 4444 | 100 |

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by id) pos
  from your_table
) pivot (
  any_value(area) area, 
  any_value(amount) amount 
  for pos in (1,2,3,4)
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest "conditional aggregates" based on a row number you calculate with a derived table.

```
select
      id
    , max(case when rn = 1 then area end)   as area1
    , max(case when rn = 1 then amount end) as amount1
    , max(case when rn = 2 then area end)   as area2
    , max(case when rn = 2 then amount end) as amount2
    , max(case when rn = 3 then area end)   as area3
    , max(case when rn = 3 then amount end) as amount3
    , max(case when rn = 4 then area end)   as area4
    , max(case when rn = 4 then amount end) as amount4
from (
    select
          id, area, amount
         , row_number() over(partition by ID order by area) as rn
    from yourtable
    ) d
```